# Not able to Obtain a registration token and display in Logcat in android studio

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Not able to Obtain a registration token and display in Logcat in android studio this is my InstanceIDListenerService class

```
public class GCMTokenRefreshListenerService extends InstanceIDListenerService {

//If the token is changed registering the device again
@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    Log.d("GCMRegIntentService", "GCMTokenRefreshListenerService:" );

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, GCMRegistrationIntentService.class);
    startService(intent);
}
```

this is my IntentService class file

```
public class GCMRegistrationIntentService extends IntentService {
//Constants for success and errors
public static final String REGISTRATION_SUCCESS = "RegistrationSuccess";
private static final String[] TOPICS = {"global"};

public static final String REGISTRATION_ERROR = "RegistrationError";


//Class constructor
public GCMRegistrationIntentService() {
    super("");
}


@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Log.d("GCMRegIntentService", "token:" );

    //Registering gcm to the device

    registerGCM();
}


private void registerGCM() {
    //Registration complete intent initially null
    Intent registrationComplete = null;

    //Register token is also null
    //we will get the token on successfull registration
    //String token = null;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    try {
        //Creating an instanceid



        InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
        String token = instanceID.getToken(getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId),
                GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
        //InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);

        //Getting the token from the instance id
        //token = instanceID.getToken(getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId), GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);

        //Displaying the token in the log so that we can copy it to send push notification
        //You can also extend the app by storing the token in to your server
        Log.e("GCMRegIntentService", "token:" + token);
        // Subscribe to topic channels
        subscribeTopics(token);

        //on registration complete creating intent with success
        registrationComplete = new Intent(REGISTRATION_SUCCESS);

        //Putting the token to the intent
        //registrationComplete.putExtra("token", token);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //If any error occurred
        Log.w("GCMRegIntentService", "Registration error");
        registrationComplete = new Intent(REGISTRATION_ERROR);
    }

    //Sending the broadcast that registration is completed
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(registrationComplete);
}
private void subscribeTopics(String token) throws IOException {
    GcmPubSub pubSub = GcmPubSub.getInstance(this);
    for (String topic : TOPICS) {
        pubSub.subscribe(token, "/topics/" + topic, null);
    }
}
```

this is my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<!-- needed for older devices -
 used to check app background / foreground status -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />

<!-- START Added for GCM -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<permission
    android:name="nath.prem.com.premgcmproject.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="nath.prem.com.premgcmproject.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<!-- END Added for GCM -->

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>



    <!-- START Added for GCM -->

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="nath.prem.com.premgcmproject" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name="nath.prem.com.premgcmproject.GCMPushReceiverService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service
        android:name="nath.prem.com.premgcmproject.GCMTokenRefreshListenerService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service
        android:name="nath.prem.com.premgcmproject.GCMRegistrationIntentService"
        android:exported="false">

    </service>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <!-- END Added for GCM -->
</application>
```

this is my project based gradle file dependencies

```
   dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2'


}
```

this is my app-based gradle file content dependencies

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0"
```

getting this error message

```
'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zzb
07-25 15:08:54.919 19852-19874/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[]
                                                   java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat
                                                       at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.zzdL(Unknown Source)
                                                       at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                       at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                       at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                       at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.getInstance(Unknown Source)
                                                       at nath.prem.com.premgcmproject.GCMRegistrationIntentService.registerGCM(GCMRegistrationIntentService.java:60)
                                                       at nath.prem.com.premgcmproject.GCMRegistrationIntentService.onHandleIntent(GCMRegistrationIntentService.java:41)
                                                       at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
                                                       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
07-25 15:08:54.961 520-539/? E/AppErrorDialog: Failed to get
```

Comment: what output are you getting? do you get null?

Comment: the error message i had included @Arthur Thompson

Comment: try using play-services-gcm instead of play-services, also update to 9.2.1 and see if that helps

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your app gralde file.

```
 //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.2.1'
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0'
```

**Update:**

**Manifest:** replace my `com.nextage.photoeditor` package name replace with yours

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />


 <permission
        android:name="com.nextage.photoeditor.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />


  <uses-permission android:name="com.nextage.photoeditor.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />



<!--GCM Integration-->

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

                <category android:name="com.nextage.bottlephotoframes" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name="com.nextage.util.MyGcmListenerService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>


        <service
            android:name="com.nextage.util.MyInstanceIDListenerService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service
            android:name="com.nextage.util.RegistrationIntentService"
            android:exported="false"></service>
        <!--End-->
```

App Gradle:

add this dependency `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.2.1'` remove all other which you add for gcm.

Assume your launcher class is `SplashActivity`

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

       // other tasks .....
       RegisterRecivers();

    }

  private void RegisterRecivers() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, RegistrationIntentService.class);
    intent.putExtra(Constants.SENDER_ID, getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId)); // your GCM here.make sure its correct.
    intent.putExtra(Constants.STRING_IDENTIFIER, stringId);
    startService(intent);

  }
}
```

**RegistrationIntentService**

```
public class RegistrationIntentService extends IntentService {

    private static final String TAG = "RegIntentService";
    Context mContext;

    public RegistrationIntentService() {
        super(TAG);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        String token = "";
        mContext = this;

        Intent regCompleteIntent = new Intent(Constants.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE);

        try {
            String string_identifier = extras.getString(Constants.STRING_IDENTIFIER);
            token = InstanceID.getInstance(this)
                    .getToken(getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId), GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
            Log.i("my toekn",token);
            //sendRegistrationToServer(token);
            regCompleteIntent.putExtra(Constants.SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER, true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            regCompleteIntent.putExtra(Constants.SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER, false);
        }

    }
```

Comment: done but not showing token in Logcat in IntentService class.So, not working yet..

Comment: @premnath show how you are running your service in oncreate Or where you care starting your intent service?

Comment: @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.d("GCMRegIntentService", "inside MainActivity" );
        //Initiate GCM request
        Intent gcmIntent = new Intent(this, GCMRegistrationIntentService.class);
        startService(gcmIntent);//here i am calling the service
    }

Comment: yes you can but seriously you didt add full information. i am making and update for you see answer in 5 mins.

Comment: @premnath if my post helps you little please vote up and tick mark.

Answer (score 0):

Try this its work for me:

Step1-> Add your app to Firebase and get googleplay-services.json and paste in your project and apply all dependencies.
this is my app graddle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "kliff.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

now my project graddle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to       all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

now comming to my app: 
create Tokenservice.java and MyFirebaseMessagingService.java

here is my tokenservice.java

```
public class TokenService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    // Get updated InstanceID token.
    String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    Log.w("notification", refreshedToken);
    sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
}

private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
}
}
```

This is my MyFirebaseMessagingService.java:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    // Create and show notification
    sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
}

private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_ic_notification)
            .setContentTitle("FCM Message")
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
}
}
```

and you have to add these in manifest under application tag:

```
  <service
        android:name=".TokenService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```